# Keep <img> always at the end of text line

Tags: css

Is there any CSS workaround to make the pdf/doc/ppt icon always sit at the end of text line, without using a background image? When there is not enough space for the icon image, it will sit in second line alone. I'm wondering if there is anything similar as `white-space:nowrap`?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="v1.pdf">Lorem Ipsum is simaorem Ipsum.  (3MB, PDF)</a>
        <img src="images/pdf.gif" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

`<ul>` has a fixed width.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. When you run out of space what do you expect to happen to both the text and the image?

Comment: Why dont you want to use a background image?  A nice way to do this is use an attribute selector like `a[href$='.pdf']` and then add your icon as an image there.

Comment: `<image>` --> `<img>` I believe the OP wants the image to "stick" to the `<a>`, and not be by itself on the next line. As if it were the last word of the text with `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: `image`? You mean `img`? Are you looking for `float: right`?

Comment: For instance, <ul> has a fixed width 200px, when <a> takes up 190px, <img>(15px) will break into second line. I wonder if we can keep <img> stay at the first line even if there is no enough space. As we know, by using "white-space:nowrap", text will never wrap to the next line. So is there anyway we can have similar solution for <img>?

Comment: background image and attribute selector is a brilliant solution, but users need more control on icon images.

Comment: If you want only the text to wrap when needed and not the image, not sure what's wrong with Qtax's suggestion. Float that sucker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are text, or “inline content,” from the perspective of layout. Thus, you can use same techniques as for preventing line breaks in text. The `nobr` markup prevents line breaks and works universally in browsers, though standards-writers have frowned upon it. If needed you can use its standardized, less reliable, more verbose sister: `white-space: nowrap` in CSS, together with some inline markup like `span`.

Here the problem is that you would need “overlapping” markup: ... `(3MB, <nobr>PDF)</a><img ...></nobr>` (i.e., open a `nobr` element inside the `a` element but close the `a` before `nobr`). While this works, it violates HTML syntax rules, so I’d suggest that you move some text out of the `a` element (it probably does not need to be there):

```
<a href="v1.pdf">Lorem Ipsum is simaorem Ipsum.</a>  (3MB, <nobr>PDF)
<img src="images/pdf.gif" alt=""></nobr>
```

or

```
<a href="v1.pdf">Lorem Ipsum is simaorem Ipsum.</a>  (3MB, <span 
style="white-space: nowrap">PDF) <img src="images/pdf.gif" alt=""></span>
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to simply have it as a background image on an inline element? The link could remain intact and no white-space tricks would be needed.

Comment: Correct, will consider this as a content issue, get the users to simplify the text instead. But personally I would go for attribute selector solution.

Comment: @GGG, the question said “without using a background image.” And among other things, when a document is printed, background images normally do not appear.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela he also says in a comment "background image and attribute selector is a brilliant solution..." I can't see how this approach would be in any way preferable to the background image thing. If printing is a must and the `img` is already in the DOM, he can simply do the background thing and hide the `img` with a `screen` media rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an inline child to your list item and give it a background image.

```
<ul>
  <li><span class='bg'><a href="v1.pdf">Lorem Ipsum is simaorem Ipsum.  (3MB, PDF)</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

...

```
li .bg {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  padding-right: 24px
}
```

See a demo here: http://tinkerbin.com/qbwNWFBb

Comment: The image being used in the Tinker isn't loading (invalid URL) so I can't judge if the positioning and padding constitute a flexible approach. ;-)

Comment: @GregPettit I think it's just tinkerbin messing up. Check it out in my very alpha jsFiddle ripoff - http://testjs.net/src/?gist=ad543741b1b9afdf4fbf warning, this site only works in chrome and will *hang firefox*. You can move and resize the preview "window" to see the effect.

Comment: I dunno what's going on, but that link just isn't available. Copy and paste it into an address bar and Github gives you a "repository not found". Sorry! (The image I mean. Just the image used in the bg)

Comment: @GregPettit http://tinkerbin.com/qbwNWFBb / http://testjs.net/src/?gist=ad543741b1b9afdf4fbf

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li a:after {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/16/16');
}
```

Comment: it seems we can not control the image position when using :after.